# Send response headers from ASP.NET Core v2.2 WebAPI application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an API controller that accepts file uploads and has a return type of `void`. I need to return content, let's say a name, from the API controller to the client (JavaScript - success handler). How do I do it?

I have tried using response headers in the API controller. But with no success. here is the part of code below.

```cs
public void MyAPIController(IList<IFormFile> Files)
{
    try
    {

       . . . . . . . . . . 
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    Response.StatusCode = 200;
                    Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "File Uploaded";
                    Response.Headers.Add("ModifiedName", "myImage");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.StatusCode = 204;
        Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "No Content";
        Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = e.Message;

    }
}
```

```js
function SuccessHandler(args) {
    var modified = args.currentTarget.getResponseHeader('ModifiedName'); 
}
```

Comment: "I have an API controller that [...] has a return type of void. I need to return content [...]. How do I do it?" *Don't return `void`.* Return the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an API controller that accepts file uploads and has a return type of void. I need to return content, let's say a name, from the API controller to the client (JavaScript - success handler). How do I do it?

When used as the return type for a method, `void` specifies that the method doesn't return a value.

ASP.NET Core offers the following options for Web API controller action return types:

- Specific type

The simplest action returns a primitive or complex data type (for example, `string` or a custom object type).

- IActionResult

The [IActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) return type is appropriate when multiple [ActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) return types are possible in an action. The `ActionResult` types represent various HTTP status codes. Some common return types falling into this category are BadRequestResult (400), NotFoundResult (404), and OkObjectResult (200).

- ActionResult< T >

ASP.NET Core 2.1 introduces the [ActionResult< T >](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) return type for Web API controller actions. It enables you to return a type deriving from ActionResult or return a specific type.

Reference :

[Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/december/choosing-the-proper-return-type-for-webapi-controller-actions/